# .htaccess help: RewriteRule entire website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently launched a website into it's production environment.

This entire website will be in this folder structure:
/root/v1/website.com/index.php

The help I need is with .htaccess. When I'm upgrading an environment I require 0 downtime, so I want to make the next version of the website in a folder named:
/root/v2/website.com/index.php and available to switch over immediately.

basically "flip a switch", by sending all traffic to the corresponding folder in the current version.

So for example, right now, I would like all traffic that goes from http://www.website.com/cookies/aregreat.php to be opened at:
/root/v1/website.com/cookies/aregreat.php

This would apply to images, js and css files too

And then I can obviously change the version from inside the .htaccess and the rest will work itself out.

I'm not familiar with RewriteRule and i'm not too great with regex, the closest I've got to solving the problem is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /../v1.0.0/$1
```

Which is probably totally wrong. Is this even possible?

All help is welcome.

Many Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you really want 'all traffic' to use the new version, I would not use an .htacess file for this, but a symbolic link.  In root you'd have one link 'released' that points to v1.  Create it like this

```
ln -s /root/v1 /root/released
```

Point your vhost at released.  When you want to switch, do a one line command:

```
rm -rf /root/released; ln -s /root/v2 root/released
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a shared server and as far as I'm aware (I could be wrong) I don't have permission to change that and they're all preset.

Comment: @DanielBeddows Do you have access to the virtual host config as scott mentions above?

Comment: I will give it a try and post my results, many thanks.

EDIT: I think this will cause problems, I have a few websites hosted under the same user, won't it effect every site?

Answer (score 0):

How about configuring it in your apache virtual host configuration ([DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot))?

Comment: I'm on a shared server and as far as I'm aware I don't have access to the configuration.

Although I'm led to believe I can use shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in .htaccess, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folderV2/
RewriteRule (.*) /folderV2/$1 [L]
```

Note: I haven't tested this, I'm not 100% sure that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In an htaccess file in your document root (would be n `/root/.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v[0-9.]+/website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/website.com/$1 [L]
```

You'd just need to change the `v1` to whatever version you have and save the file and you'd flipped the switch.

---

> Unfortunately this doesn't work, but this is the type of solution that I would like. Would it be possible to rewrite this to work on subdomains too?

Yeah, you can match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and backreference using the `%` symbol:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v[0-9.]+/%2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/%2/$1 [L]
```

Here, `%2` is going to be whatever matches after an optional `www.`. So if the URL is:

```
http://www.domain.com/cookies/aregreat.php
```

Then you should get rewritten to `/v1/domain.com/cookies/aregreat.php`, and:

```
http://cakes.domain.com/chocolate/cake.php
```

should get rewritten to `/v1/cakes.domain.com/chocolate/cake.php`, etc.

Comment: This seems to work. My apologizes but would it be possible to rewrite it to work under website.com and any subdomain? Or is that not feasible? Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, but this is the type of solution that I would like. Would it be possible to rewrite this to work on subdomains too?